# Quantum Signal Operator and the unitary state preparation oracle?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, unitarity, oracles

I am looking into IL Chuang and GH Low's [Hamiltonian Simulation with Qubitization paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06546).

[image: signal operator and unitary state preparation oracle]

I am very confused on the terminology and motivation behind definition 1.

I do not understand what the unitary oracle, $\hat{U}$ or the unitary state preparation oracle $\hat{G}$ are meant to represent here. Is it simply that $\hat{H}$ can be decomposed into them? Also what is the $\mathcal{I}_s$ meant to represent?

I think that a subscript, $A_x$ is meant to represent that $A$ is in an $x \times x$ Hilbert space.

However, previously in the paper, they say that $\hat{H} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$, $\hat{U} \in \mathbb{C}^{Nd \times Nd}$, and $\left | G \right > \in \mathbb{C}^{d}$ If this is true, then $(\left < G \right | \otimes \mathcal{I}_s)\hat{U}(\left | \hat{G} \right > \otimes \mathcal{I}_s) \in \mathbb{C}$, as it is essentially an inner product, not $\mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$, right?

[image]

Any help is massively appreciated. This is all so confusing. Thank you.